# Ticardio Could not connect to server

Tags: ios, paypal, titanium, appcelerator, card.io

I've installed ticardio (https://github.com/aaronksaunders/tiCardIO_IOS) for my ios titanium app but after scanning the card an alert show saying "Whoops Could not connect to server", the token is installed, and already have permissions for internet and also the phone is connected to the internet

FYI the module is working properly manually entering the card info. BUT NOT WITH THE CAMERA.

Comment: Dave from card.io here. It looks like the Titanium project you're using includes a very old version of card.io, namely version 2.3 from 2012. We're currently up to version 3.10.1. So you should probably try to find a newer Titanium integration, or else update that one to use the [latest version of card.io](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK).

Comment: Thank you Dave!, now when I try to build my proyect have the next error:

[ERROR] :   BUILD FAILED
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Debug-iphoneos/sorteosTec.app/sorteosTec normal armv7
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)

Can you help me with this?

Comment: You'll need to provide a more complete copy of the entire error message, with the details of why there is a linker error. (My preliminary guess is that the code you're using needs to be updated to stay compatible with the newer version of the card.io library.)

Comment: it is usually best to start by opening a ticket with the developer of the module?